# CSS not being applied to print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

**What I have done**

I am working on an application where a receipt is generated and printed. To do this printing, I create a table, style it and print it. I don't want to print the entire page so I select just this div that contains the table to print like this.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function printData() {


        var divToPrint = document.getElementById("inv");
        newWin = window.open("");
        newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();

    }
</script>
```

**Problem**

Problem is that, I cannot get the CSS to persist from the page to the print.

**What have i tried?**

I have tried to import a print CSS page as shown below and that hasn't done anything. 
Also in the main file if I change `<style>` to `<style media=print>` the css is removed from my table as expected but not being applied to my print.

Would appreciate it if I could be pointed in the right direction.

Regards

```
<link href='/Content/css/theme-print.css' rel='stylesheet' media="print" type='text/css' />
    <style>


    .invoice-box {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    background-color:green;
    }

    .invoice-box table {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: inherit;
    text-align: left;
    }


        </style>
</head>
    <body >
    <div class="invoice-box" id="inv">
        <table style="background-color:blue" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" id="labelData" width:500px;>
            <tr class="top">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="title">
                                <img src="" style=" width:75px;">
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                Date Received :@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.hiddenDate)

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

theme-print.css

```
@media print {

    .invoice-box {
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 30px;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 24px;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #555;
        background-color: green;
    }

        .invoice-box table {
            width: 100%;
            line-height: inherit;
            text-align: left;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your new window is a seperate environment. You'll need to copy over everything necessary to render the document. Think of it as constructing a complete web page. As it stands, you're just copying over an html fragment.

Comment: @Ouroborus Oh, I see that, how can I "copy" or set the style for a new window before it's even created...

Comment: Same way you added html, using `document.write()`.

Comment: Maybe also consider that you might be better off having the web server generate the printable receipt. It's already generating the one you're displaying. Having the server generate a printable receipt as well means you'd just need to open a url in a new tab.

Comment: Another solution is to have your page include print styles that reformat the page as you want but only when printed. Then you'd just need to print your existing page.

Comment: @Ouroborus I tried to implement your solution B but again that did not work. print styles are not applying to the table

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the stylesheet via script to the newWin variable, before adding your content.

Here's an explicit example:

```
newWin.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Page!</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path-to-your.css"></head><body>');
newWin.document.write( divToPrint.outerHTML );
newWin.document.write('</body></html>');
```